# "e.g." versus "i.e."

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations

What are the differences between these two abbreviations? What are the appropriate situations to use each?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As reported by the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> e.g. /ˌi ˈdʒi/
>   abbreviation
>   for example.
>   ORIGIN from Latin *exempli gratia* (*for the sake of an example*).
>
> i.e. /ˌaɪ ˈi/
>   abbreviation
>   that is to say (used to add explanatory information or to state something in different words): *a walking boot that is synthetic, i.e., not leather or suede*.
>   ORIGIN from Latin *id est* "that is."

*E.g.* is used in expressions similar to *including,* when you are not intending to list everything that is being discussed.
*I.e.* is used when what you are introducing is equivalent to or an explanation of what comes before it in the sentence.

> I like root vegetables, e.g., potatoes.
>
> I like root vegetables; i.e., the ones that grow underground.

Answer (score 9):

There's a neat way to remember which is which: "e.g." and "example" both start with the letter "e" (so read "e.g." as "for example"); and "i.e." and "in other words" both start with the letter "i".

Answer (score 6):

Please see *the* most authoritative source: [The Oatmeal.](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie)