# What mean by I.e. and e.g?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, grammar, word-usage

Actually often we use `I.e. and e.g` but i'm not sure what exact meaning of it anybody can tell? What is exact meaning of I.e. and e.g.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are "i.e." and "e.g." pronounced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574/how-are-i-e-and-e-g-pronounced)

Comment: Have you tried looking them up in a dictionary? Is there something that remains unclear after doing so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["e.g." versus "i.e."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/e-g-versus-i-e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i.e. means 'in other words'. So here, you'd provide an extension/alternative explanation to clarify the point.

e.g. = for example. Here, illustrate the point with an example.